# Why did no one draw fractals before the early 20th century?

Tags: math-history, fractals

> Why did no one draw fractals before the early 20th century?

I've heard about art that resembles fractals, but that doesn't count. What I'm talking about is stuff like Sierpinski's triangle. Surely someone must've doodled Sierpinski's triangle centuries ago, right? It seems hard to believe that even simple fractals like Sierpinski's triangle, Von Koch Curve, Peano Curve, Viscek Fractal, or the Jerusalem Cube took so long to be drawn.

Update: By drawing, I mean drawing enough iterations of the fractal on whatever surface you're using so that it is impossible to draw any more due to the thickness of your lines. Here's [something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFzL.jpg) I drew a few years ago as an example that's not perfect, but is good enough.

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question. ... That said, while fractals *per se* may be relatively new, certainly *self-similar figures* date back pretty far. After all, the simple geometric series amounts to such a thing.

Comment: Marginally related is [Who first drew the Weierstrass function?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3058/264) I'm sure that people doodled such figures, but it was very expensive and difficult to publish diagrams, especially intricate diagrams such as you're looking for. For example, on [p. viii of **Mathematical Questions with Their Solutions, from the "Educational Times"**](https://books.google.com/books?id=1I1KAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR8) (1874) there is a discussion of a problem in which an infinite sequence of triangles are inscribed in an infinite sequence of circles, without a diagram.

Comment: For those interested, I found the reference I gave in my previous comment by searching in google-books, date restricted to 19th century, the phrase "ad infinitum" along with one or more words such as "triangle", "circle", etc.

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, depending what you mean by "drawing", it was simply not easy to draw such stuff until the advent of computer-assisted drawing.

I seem to recall that J. Peter Matelski (who started grad school a year or two after I did, at Princeton, c. 1974) was one of the first people to draw (one way or another) a picture of some part of the Mandelbrot set.

EDIT: in the late 1980's, I myself did "hack" my dot-matrix printer so that it could print a part of a Mandelbrot set. Had to set "characters" that were the various dots-or-not in the small print-blocks (or whatever they were called)... and also cause there to be no inter-line spacing... and so on. A fun exercise, but limited resolution.

Comment: Many of the examples I mentioned could be drawn by hand. If someone drew the first 5 or 6 iterations of Sierpinski's triangle, that would count even though you can't draw infinitely many. I'll update the question.

Comment: [An Egyptian column](https://users.math.yale.edu/public_html/People/frame/Fractals/Panorama/Art/AfricanArt/EgyptianColumn.html), perhaps of interest?

Comment: I remember reading about the first computer printings of the Mandelbrot set that they had to specifically tell the printer attendants not to clean up the print. Because printers often printed small specks that shouldn't be there, they often took a scalpel and scrape those away. However, for the Mandelbrot set, those specks are actually there.

Comment: Aside: The first computer-drawn picture of the Mandelbrot set appeared in a paper by Brooks and Matelsky (who did not name the set after anybody, of course) and was rather coarse. Their paper followed by the one by Mandelbrot, who worked at the time in IBM and had access to better computers and printers. Brooks and Matelsky were interested in the "freeness problem" for 2-generated subgroups of $SL(2,C)$, which is why they invented the set. Why Mandelbrot was interested in this set, I do not know.

Comment: see this intriguing [answer to *Grid spacing, iterations used in the 1978 first published rendering of the Mandelbrot set?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3510304/284619)